# Requisitos de las medallas

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Por curiosidad, estaba mirando los requisitos de las medallas, y los he comparado con los requisitos de la versión inglesa.

Son **exactamente** iguales.

¿ No deberían adaptarse a la cantidad de usuarios del sitio español ? Al menos, algunas.

Por ejemplo, la medalla `legendario`:

```
Gana 200 puntos diarios de reputación 150 veces.
```

Entiendo que en la versión inglesa, con *muchimillones* de usuarios, sea *posible* conseguirla.

Pero en la versión española, con bastantes menos usuarios (y con la poca predisposición de estos a puntuar), esa medalla en concreto es **imposible**.

Parece lógico suponer que la máxima cantidad de puntos a los que un usuario puede aspirar *en un dia* es proporcional a la máxima cantidad de usuarios que pueden puntuar *en un dia*. Si hay menos usuarios, hay menos cantidad de *puntos a aspirar*.

Comment: no es versión española, es en español. No todos somos de España.

Comment: Cierto. Lamento el error por mi parte.

Comment: Sí estoy de acuerdo en que las medallas deberían adaptarse, pero creo que más a los tiempos que a los sitios. Por ejemplo, en [so] es relativamente fácil conseguir la medalla de oro Famous Question, pues conseguid 10K visitas a base de tiempo es bastante plausible.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿ No deberían adaptarse a la cantidad de usuarios del sitio español ?

**No.**

Las medallas nunca se han adaptado al % de usuarios activos ni nada por el estilo y lo veo bien.

Pensadlo de otra manera; si las medallas fueran más "fáciles" de ganar al principio eso desvirtuaría esas medallas y a la vez causaría desigualdad para nuevos usuarios que están por venir.

De esta manera las medallas tiene aún más valor.

> esa medalla en concreto es **imposible.**

**De momento.** Vamos creciendo poco a poco pero de manera lineal y hacia arriba. Vamos bien.

Para finalizar me gustaría añadir que las medallas tienen *poca importancia*. Lo realmente importante es la calidad que uno pueda aportar en el sitio y las medallas ya llegarán por sí solas.

Comment: Creo que sería al contrario; es decir, equilibraría las cosas entre los usuarios actuales, con pocos *clientes*, y los futuros, con mayor número de *clientes*.

Answer (score -1):

Haciendo cálculos...

200 puntos * 150 -> 30<sub>k</sub> puntos.

En StackOverflow hay 19<sub>k</sub>132 usuarios... Si 20 usuarios te dan +1 en una respuesta (+10) en un día, ya se logra un día... Otro día, otros 20 usuarios... Así hasta llegar a 150 días -> 3<sub>k</sub> usuarios.

Creo que la cantidad registrada sobrepasa los usuarios necesarios... Pero lamentablemente la mayoría no está activo, es probable que solo 300 usuarios vengan regularmente al sitio, es decir, un %2. De todos modos... Se pueden ir turnando, 20 usuarios durante 10 días hasta llegar a 300, de manera que es posible obtener esa medalla.

Para eso hay que responder mucho y bastante bien, de manera documentada, para que los usuarios se asombren cada vez.

Comment: Ok. Gracias por la aclaración. No sabía la cantidad de usuarios registrados, pero me parecía injusto usar los mismos parámetros que en la versión inglesa. Veo que es una burrada, haya los usuarios que haya :-(

Comment: @Trauma También puedes tocar el botón del engranaje para mostrar un progreso diferente. Actualmente veo "Autobiógrafo"... No le veo mucho sentido que muestres eso.

Comment: No lo se, lo toqué una vez por toquetear las cosas y lo deje xD